# Refresh output line containing download percentage

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that has to download several files from the www.
To make it more expressive I've just added a download hook to calculate the downloading percentage of the file that has being downloaded. Printing it out on the terminal produces a lot of output because I rewrite the same line each time the percentage counter is incremented, example:

```
1% - Downloading test.jpg
2% - Downloading test.jpg
... and so on
```

I'd like to obtain something like many bash scripts or programs (such as "apt-get" from ubuntu): refresh the line containing the percentage without have to write several times the same line containing the the updated percentage.

How can I do that?
Thanks.

[edit]
I'm using Python3.2 to develop the file downloader.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Didn't find it before posting this.

Comment: related: [Download progressbar for Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13895723/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need curses:

http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `\r` (carriage return) and write directly to the terminal with `sys.stdout.write`:

```
import time
import sys
for i in range(101):
    sys.stdout.write('%3d%%\r' % i)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Or a little more Python 3-ish:

```
import time
for i in range(101):
    print('{:3}%'.format(i),end='\r')
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Comment: @Patrick: requires running at a command line console. Most IDEs don't support it.

Comment: Was running it in xterm (rxvt). Didn't work.

Comment: python-3 worked for me