# Download progressbar for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, progress-bar

I need a progress to show during file download for Python 3. 
I have seen a few topics on Stackoverflow, but considering that I'm a noob at programming and nobody posted a complete example, just fractions of it, or the one that I can make work on Python 3, none are good for me...

additional info:

ok, so i have this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import configparser
#checks for files which need to be downloaded
print('    Downloading...')
file = urlopen(file_url)
#progress bar here
output = open('downloaded_file.py','wb')
output.write(file.read())
output.close()
os.system('downloaded_file.py')
```

script is run through python command line

Comment: This question is missing a lot of helpful information:
Where do you want this progress bar? In the console? On a web page? In some desktop app? How are you downlading the file? etc etc

Comment: (urllib2 in Python 2 is more or less the same as urllib in Python 3)

Comment: i noticed that urllib.request in python 3 is what urllib2 is python 2... correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: Related: [Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279)

Comment: @Cœur the link is useful (for those who need Python 2). You could move the link into the comments if you'd like¶ Python 3 code can be improved (and therefore it is not useful to prevent future answers).

Comment: Related: [Python urllib2 Progress Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028517/python-urllib2-progress-hook)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is [`urlretrieve()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) that downloads an url to a file and allows to specify a reporthook callback to report progess:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
    if totalsize > 0:
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize
        s = "\r%5.1f%% %*d / %d" % (
            percent, len(str(totalsize)), readsofar, totalsize)
        sys.stderr.write(s)
        if readsofar >= totalsize: # near the end
            sys.stderr.write("\n")
    else: # total size is unknown
        sys.stderr.write("read %d\n" % (readsofar,))

urlretrieve(url, 'downloaded_file.py', reporthook)
```

Here's a GUI progress bar:

```
import sys
from threading import Event, Thread
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def download(url, filename):
    root = progressbar = quit_id = None
    ready = Event()
    def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
        nonlocal quit_id
        if blocknum == 0: # started downloading
            def guiloop():
                nonlocal root, progressbar
                root = Tk()
                root.withdraw() # hide
                progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=400)
                progressbar.grid()
                # show progress bar if the download takes more than .5 seconds
                root.after(500, root.deiconify)
                ready.set() # gui is ready
                root.mainloop()
            Thread(target=guiloop).start()
        ready.wait(1) # wait until gui is ready
        percent = blocknum * blocksize * 1e2 / totalsize # assume totalsize > 0
        if quit_id is None:
            root.title('%%%.0f %s' % (percent, filename,))
            progressbar['value'] = percent # report progress
            if percent >= 100:  # finishing download
                quit_id = root.after(0, root.destroy) # close GUI

    return urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)

download(url, 'downloaded_file.py')
```

On Python 3.3 `urlretrieve()` has different `reporthook` interface ([see issue 16409](http://bugs.python.org/issue16409)). To workaround it, you could access the previous interface via `FancyURLopener`:

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
urlretrieve = FancyURLopener().retrieve
```

To update the progress bar within the same thread, you could inline `urlretrieve()` code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from urllib.request import urlopen

def download2(url, filename):
    response = urlopen(url)
    totalsize = int(response.headers['Content-Length']) # assume correct header
    outputfile = open(filename, 'wb')

    def download_chunk(readsofar=0, chunksize=1 << 13):
        # report progress
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize # assume totalsize > 0
        root.title('%%%.0f %s' % (percent, filename,))
        progressbar['value'] = percent

        # download chunk
        data = response.read(chunksize)
        if not data: # finished downloading
            outputfile.close()
            root.destroy() # close GUI
        else:
            outputfile.write(data) # save to filename
            # schedule to download the next chunk
            root.after(0, download_chunk, readsofar + len(data), chunksize)

    # setup GUI to show progress
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw() # hide
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=400)
    progressbar.grid()
    # show progress bar if the download takes more than .5 seconds
    root.after(500, root.deiconify)
    root.after(0, download_chunk)
    root.mainloop()

download2(url, 'downloaded_file.py')
```

Comment: @Mirac7: I've added variant that shows GUI and download the file from within the same thread.

Comment: Good and complete answer +1

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Is there a possible way to include download speed in a `reporthook`?

Comment: @GughanRavikumar yes. Store the time you've received the last block and divide it by a block size to get the current  download speed.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Silly me!! I didn't think of that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GughanRavikumar it could look like: `t = time.monotonic(); speed = blocksize / (t - last[0]); average_speed = readsofar / (t - start); last[0] = t`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I got it working with something similar. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I think this piece of code can help you. I'm not quite sure it's exactly what you want. At least  it should give you something to work on.

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import ttk
from urllib.request import urlopen


def download(event):
    file = urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
    output = open('downloaded_file.txt', 'wb')
    lines= file.readlines()
    i = len(lines)

    for line in lines:
        output.write(line)
        pbar.step(100/i)

    output.close()
    file.close()




root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Download bar')

pbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=300)
pbar.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

btn = tkinter.Button(root, text="Download")
# bind to left mouse button click
btn.bind("<Button-1>", download)
btn.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This works, I've tried it.

Comment: I'm recieving error io.UnsupportedOperation: seek... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think seek() method doesn't work with urlopen().Remove the line file.seek(0) and see the results.

Comment: already tried... it works fine, but when i click download, it simply creates empty script, and progressbar is empty.

Comment: @doru To avoid opening the URL twice, why not assign `file.readlines()` to a variable?

Comment: @poorsod You're right! Thanks a lot! I've already (re)edited the answer. +1 for this.

Comment: can you tell me how to make percent progress displayed through progress bar?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but I'll find out and let you know.

Comment: thanks... i have only one file to be downloaded, so i can't make use of progress bar like the one in your example in this specific situation...

Comment: @doru: you could get an approximate file size from `Content-Length` header as urlretrieve() does. It will allow you to show the percent progress.