# Unable to process python subprocess stderr on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, stderr

I am trying to simple file copy operation using `dd` under Windows. The code is simple. Just open the command using subprocess and read `stderr`. Then process the `stderr` to show the progress of the operation. Here is the sample/simple code which I an trying to accomplish:-

```
import time
import signal
import subprocess
import os

def dd_win():
    windd = "dd.exe"
    in_file = os.path.join("E:", "test-in.iso")
    out_file = os.path.join("E:", "test-out.iso")
    parameter1 = "if=" + in_file
    parameter2 = "of=" + out_file
    parameter3 = "bs=1M"
    parameter4 = "--progress"
    command = [windd, parameter1, parameter2, parameter4]
    print command
    dd_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=0)

    while dd_process.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(.1)
        line = dd_process.stderr.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print ">>>>>", line.strip()
    if dd_process.poll() is not None:
        print "Process finished."

dd_win()
```

Here is wht I got as an output. I could see the `stderr` but unable to process the transfer bytes to convert in to mega bytes:-

```
C:\Users\user\Documents>python test.py
['dd.exe', 'if=E:test-in.iso', 'of=E:test-out.iso', '--progress']
>>>>> rawwrite dd for windows version 0.6beta3.
>>>>> Written by John Newbigin <jn@it.swin.edu.au>
>>>>> This program is covered by terms of the GPL Version 2.
>>>>>
175,882,240  # <--- Problem output line. Unable to assign to other variable for progress calculation
Process finished.
```

I actually do not know where the numbers are coming from. Is it from `stderr` or buffer? If it is from `stderr` then ">>>>>" should have be printed before the numbers. I work on Windows 7 and using windows version of dd.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the print statements from your code, does the `175,882,240` still appear? Can you redirect stdout and stderr from your program to files so that you can see which stream `175,882,240` is coming from?

Comment: If I remove `print ">>>>>", line.strip()` statement then I can not see any output on the screen.

Comment: If you run your dd command in your terminal, do you see "175,882,240" printed, or is it only when you execute it in Python?

Comment: I got an error that `close_fds` is not supported on windows platform.

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment about close_fds - it's set to True by default anyway, tho if Windows doesn't support it it might be related.

Comment: It's ?possible? that the line is weird because it contains a ton of control characters. E.g. If dd provides a progressbar or something the output might look like `1\r2\r3\r...\r\n175\n`. I can't work out exactly how that would break readline, but you might be helped by printing out the length of each line (control characters will inflate the length) and/or printing out `",".join(ind(char) for char in line)` or similar. This would at least rule out the possibility of this happening, though I'm clutching at strawas a little here tho!

Comment: What is `ind` in the statement you have written `",".join(ind(char) for char in line)`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant `ord(char)`. Ref https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord

Comment: I got `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72688/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-sundar-ima).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat, the numbers are coming from stderr. By printing the ascii-indexes of each character in line, we discovered that the final line returned by readline() is `\t75,881,728 \r175,882,240 \r\n`. It looks like the `\r` embedded in the middle of this string (which DD outputs) is confusing your code.

Comment: OP could enable `universal_newlines=True` to treat `\r` as a newline. `\r` may be used to report progress (e.g., [see how `reporthook()` uses `\r`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13895723/4279)) -- it may instruct terminal to move the cursor to the beginning of the line.